# Problems with CocoaPods GoogleCloudMessaging (Xcode 7.2)

Tags: objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I added GoogleCloudMessaging with CocoaPods to the project. 
The file "Pods" contains the following code:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
platform :ios, '8.1' 
dependency 'libPusher', '1.1' 
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

After install I had problems with library -lPods, but the problem was solved by removing the content of **Build Settings -> Linkers -> Other Linkers Flags**.

As result I got next error:

```
ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the . xcworkspace file and not the .xcodeproj file?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem: it was necessary to use the

```
$ pod update
```

from the terminal